# Where can I find modern business laws dealing specifically with online businesses?

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, money, internet, business

I'm looking for something all-encompassing, specifically for an online business. Whether you're selling products, services or software online, I want to know how to deal with it in regards to Shabbat and everything else.

Comment: Sefer on such topics http://www.thelakewoodscoop.com/news/2013/10/new-sefer-business-and-e-commerce-on-shabbos-based-on-the-rulings-of-harav-shlomo-miller-shlita.html

Comment: Ha! I totally bought that yesterday!

Comment: Hope it satisfies what your looking for.

Answer (score 2):

[`Business​Halacha.com`](http://businesshalacha.com/) has articles and a question-and-answer hotline and was recommended to me (by someone I trust in matters of *halacha*) for all questions of *Choshen Mishpat* (torts, bailments, loans, rentals, sales, etc.) and *ribis* (interest).